# meteor iron router execute action only if path changed

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want my iron-router before hook to execute only if my path changed.

I have a keyword-search field in my header (layout) and I was this field to reset when I change page but not when I stay on the same page and trigger some events.

How can I do this?

This is what I have:

```
Router.onBeforeAction ->
  $(".notification").remove()
  Session.set("keyword_search","")
  $("#keyword-search").val("")
  return
```

The onBeforeAction hook is executed even if I click a button  that doesn't change the route. This is not what I want...

I tried using document.referrer like this

```
Router.onBeforeAction ->
  $(".notification").remove()
  if document.referrer.indexOf @path == -1  #only if new path
    Session.set("keyword_search","")
    $("#keyword-search").val("")
```

but it doesn't work because when I click a button the page, the referrer is still the last page with a different url and my keyword_search field is reset.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to use the onRun hook.

onRun is triggered at every route change (and not at every Router startup as I thought...).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the path in a Session variable and check to see if it’s changed? From your second code block:

```
Router.onBeforeAction ->
  $(".notification").remove()
  unless Session.equals("current_path", @path) # only if new path
    Session.set("current_path", @path)
    Session.set("keyword_search", "")
    $("#keyword-search").val("")
```

Comment: I tried with session variables but it was recalculating the stuff when the session variable was set and at the end current was always equal to previous path